# Set values in a column on a sheet from a 1d array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that gathers Full Names contained within an email group 
The idea is to have an up to date list of members of a team to use within a drop down.

It is working correctly but I can't seem to get it to `setValues()` Everything I have tried, either only lists one name from the list, all values in one cell or doesn't work. I think it's to do with the fact it's a 1 dimensional array but I could be wrong.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "email@email.com";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var str = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +  " members: ";
  var valueRange=[];
  valueRange[0]=[];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var email = user.getEmail();
    var contact =  ContactsApp.getContact(email);
    if(contact!=null){
    valueRange[i]=[];
      valueRange[i].push (contact.getFullName());
      }
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet name");
  var numberRows = valueRange.length;
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numberRows, 1);
  range.setValues(valueRange);
}
```

I am struggling with out to get these values, into Column1, Row1, on my sheet like follows in seperate cells:

Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4

The array is as follows: [Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 5, etc]

Please help, hope this all makes sense!

Comment: One question: You say Column1, Row1 BUT seperate cells? You probably mean starting with Column1, Row1 for Name1. Do you want to paste the other names in the same row or in the same column? Also, the script version you included does not contain any names but UserLoginId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To output your values into a value range and assign this value range to a row:

Based on the code you provided, perform the following modification:

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "emailgroup@email.com";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var str = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +  " members: ";
  var valueRange=[];
  valueRange[0]=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var email = user.getEmail();
    var contact =  ContactsApp.getContact(email);
valueRange[i]=[];
    if(contact!=null){
      valueRange[i].push (contact.getFullName());
    }else{
      valueRange[i].push ("");
    }
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("INSERT HERE THE NAME OF YOUR SHEET");
  var numberColumns = valueRange[0].length;
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberColumns);
  range.setValues(valueRange);
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `setValues()` expect a 2-D value range, that is a nested array with the dimensions [numberRows][numberColumns]. For a row, it is a 2-D array with the height of 1 and the width corresponding to the number of your values. For a column, it would be exactly the opposite.
- [push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) is a Javascript method useful for populating the array elements of the value range with your values

To insert values vertically (in one column) instead of horizontally - loop through rows instead of columns. Sample:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var email = user.getEmail();
    var contact =  ContactsApp.getContact(email);
valueRange[i]=[];
    if(contact!=null){
      valueRange[i].push (contact.getFullName());
    }else{
      valueRange[i].push ("");
    }
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("INSERT HERE THE NAME OF YOUR SHEET");
  var numberRows = valueRange.length;
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numberRows, 1);
  range.setValues(valueRange);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it is throwing an error Missing ; before statement. (line 8

Comment: Okay so this is very close, except this gets the email addresses, rather than the Full Name which is what it was doing before, and it also displays them horizontally rather than vertically

Comment: I tried swapping it like this: var range = sheet.getRange(2, 8, numberColumns, 1); but this is just throwing an error

Comment: As for full names instead of emails - use the code I  provided you in the other answer instead of the one you provided here. As for the range:What is your purpose do you want to start with the cell in row 2, column 8? See here the correct syntax: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns And then you want to insert the values vertically? In this case you should loop through rows, not columns, I will update my answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this - I'm getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to  (Line 13) - if I remove [i] then I get a mismatch error number of rows to range

Comment: Which is your line 13?

Comment: Sorry `valueRange[i][0] = contact.getFullName();`

Comment: Can you add before this line `valueRange[i]=[];` ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Unfortunately still no luck getting this error message: Cannot convert Array to number[][]. (line 20,

Comment: Could you please provide your complete code to see where the error comes from?

Comment: I've edited my original question to show what I have, thanks again for your help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on holidays. I could reproduce your error for the case `contact=null` (this means that a member of the group is not in your contacts). You can solve the issue by e.g. catching the error with an `else` statement and push an empty string into the sheet for members missing in in your contacts, see my updated answer.